# How can I handle nested looping without nesting foreach statements in Perl?

Tags: perl, nested-loops

I have a Perl script which nests foreach loops as seen below.  It takes a long time:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @sites = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my @servers = ('A', 'B');
my @data_type = ("X", "Y", "Z");

foreach my $site (@sites) {
    foreach my $server_type (@servers) {
        foreach my $data (@data_type) {
            #statements
        }
    }
}
```

Nesting `foreach` statements like this takes a long time and it's hard to read and not very pretty. Can anyone suggest a better way to code this structure using hashes, or some other clever structure?

Comment: There is no problem with the code.  If you really want to do what you've written, then this is the way to do it.  If you have something else in mind, describe that.

Comment: For one thing, you have set warnings on twice. Either do it in the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/perl -w`) or do it with `use` - you don't need to do both. I prefer `use` because it's scoped, but some prefer the `-w`, perhaps precisely because it _isn't_ scoped, or perhaps because it's shorter.

Comment: @jrockway: It works fine for me, but I am just wondering if I can have any better code then this.

Comment: No, not really. If you need to work with every possible combination of values in three arrays, you're going to have to loop through all of them somehow. Might as well be a `foreach` loop.

Comment: *What* problems and *how* can values mismatch? You'll get better help if you clarify what you're worried about.

Comment: @Chris: there are lots of other ways to iterate through combinations without hard-coded loops. My Set::CrossProduct module does that, and for an arbitrary number of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what your problem is, but you could use a generic Cartesian product if you are used to SQL or something:

```
sub cartesian {
    my @C = map { [ $_ ] } @{ shift @_ };
    foreach (@_) {
        my @A = @$_;
        @C = map { my $n = $_; map { [ $n, @$_ ] } @C } @A;
    }
    return @C;
}

my @sites = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my @servers = ('A', 'B');
my @data_type = ("X", "Y", "Z");

foreach (cartesian(\@sites, \@servers, \@data_type)) {
    ($data, $server_type, $site) = @$_;
    print "$site $server_type $data\n";
}
```

Comment: I might suggest that your cartesian sub be prototyped, so that users don't have to use `\\` before all their lists. Also, ideally it should spit out the values in the same order they were put in.

Comment: Also, please `use strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: Clarification - that way, you would call it as `cartesian(@sites, @servers, @data_type)`, without the backslashes.

Comment: Even easier would be to use `Set::CrossProduct`, available on CPAN.

Comment: Don't do it that way: you have to create all the tuples in memory. :(

Answer (score 6):

Use my [Set::CrossProduct](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Set-CrossProduct) module, or use [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Loops). You shouldn't have to create hard-coded, nested structures to deal with these issues. Both of those modules can do it for you for an arbitrary number of arrays.

```
use Set::CrossProduct;

my @sites = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my @servers = ('A', 'B');
my @data_type = ("X", "Y", "Z");

my $cross = Set::CrossProduct->new( 
    [ \@sites, \@servers, \@data_type ]
    );

while( my $tuple = $cross->get ) {
    print "@$tuple\n";
    }
```

Not only that, but the cursor gives you ways to move around in the iterator so you don't have to limit yourself to the current combination. You can inspect the previous and next combinations, which might be useful for boundaries (like where the next tuple is a different server).

Watch out for people who want to create all of the combinations in memory. There's no need to do that either.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `for`.

*(sorry, couldn't resist)*

Comment: I used to be a big advocate of `foreach` - I thought using `for` should be for C-style `for` loops, to make it easier to read for maintainers ("Is this a C-style or Perl-style loop?"). Then I realized that, in Perl, you almost never need the C-style `for` loop, and now I use it exclusively.

Comment: I think JB was referring to how "for" and "foreach" are synonyms. If the asker doesn't like foreach, he can choose to spell it "for" instead.

Comment: Judging by my read of Chris Lutz's comment he understood that and was just relating that he used to reserve "for" for C-style loops and "foreach" for list iteration, then realized that he never needs C-style loops in Perl, so now he happily uses "for" exclusively.  (And if that wasn't his story, it's mine anyhow.)

Comment: Don't worry, Dave, it was my story.

Comment: In Perl 6 `foreach` is spelled `for` , and `for(;;)` is spelled `loop(;;)`

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` is preferable because it's readable. What exactly do you mean by "each array can cause problems" (what problems?) and "values can mismatch" (what values?)

Comment: nested foreachs are a pain to read and maintain. Use an iterator solution such as Algorithm::Loops or Set::CrossProduct.

Comment: Looking at your comment, he'd have to download those from CPAN. Is it better to use built-in idioms like foreach, or force the user to download external packages? I prefer solutions that have as few external dependencies as possible.

Comment: The code for my module is minimal. He could even lift it. It's not at all preferable to use foreach since it hard codes its limitations. Other solutions are flexible without the repeated monkey work you have to do every time you change the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then you asking how to use hashes with foreach to avoid mismatches that you would have in your array example?.

If so then here is one example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %sites = (

    a => { 
        A => {
            data_type => [ 'X', 'Y' ],
        }
    },

    b => {
        B => {
            data_type => [ 'Y', 'Z' ],
        }
    },

    c => {

    },
);

for my $site ( keys %sites ) {
    for my $server ( keys %{ $sites{ $site } } ) {
        for my $data ( keys %{ $sites{ $site }{ $server } } ) {
            my @data_types = @{ $sites{ $site }{ $server }{ data_type } };
            say "On site $site is server $server with $data @data_types";
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use while & each which does produces easier code on the eye:

```
while ( my ( $site, $site_info ) = each %sites ) {
    while ( my ( $server, $server_info ) = each %{ $site_info } ) {
        my @data_types = @{ $server_info->{data_type} };
        say "On site $site we have server $server with data types @data_types"
            if @data_types;
    }
}
```

Also note I removed last loop in above example because its currently superfluous with my example hash data.

NB. If you plan to amend keys or break out of loop then please read up on [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) and how it affects the iteration.

PS.  This example is not about the loop but about data being best represented as a Hash and not an Array! (though its not clear 100% from question that is so!).

Answer (score -1):

The only concern I might have when using nested loops is some ambiguity in what `$_` is.  Considering that you're not even using it, I don't think there's a better way to do what you want.

As a sidenote, I'd like to add that `$_` is well defined in this case, but as a programmer I may not want to deal with the overhead of remembering what it refers to at each step.

Do you have any *specific* concerns with the code?

Comment: Uh, he isn't using $_ anywhere.

Comment: Which is why I think he should have no problems here.

Comment: -1: "The only concern I might have here is use of egg noodles. You may not want to deal with the overhead of remembering what egg noodles have got to do with your code. However, since you avoid using it, you should have no problem with this code."

Comment: Right, except that egg noodles have nothing to do with loops in Perl, while `$_` does.

Answer (score -5):

You can use a classic `for` loop instead.

```
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#sites; $i++){
    for(my $j = 0; $j <= $#servers; $j++){
        for(my $k = 0; $k <= $#data_type; $k++){
            do_functions ...
```

But that still leaves the problems and mismatches you were reffering to. I suggest you handle these issues in the `do_functions` part.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code will skip the last element of each array. Better to use the `foreach` style, so you don't need to mess around with array indices.

Comment: I don't understand why you would recommend a less-idiomatic, more verbose "solution" that's more like a mental speed bump to maintainers, and then say "but this doesn't solve your problem". If it doesn't solve their problem, or improve their code in some way, why are you posting an answer?

Comment: I edited this to at least be somewhat correct.  Not that I would ever use <= in for loops starting from 0.  $i < @array is much easier to read.

Comment: He asked what he could use "instead". Of course this is not as nice looking as for each but is an alternative.

Comment: This isn't really an alternative. It's doing the same thing with the same problem, even if the typing looks a bit different.

Comment: In Perl `for` is simply an alias for `foreach`